# Having a little trouble with compareto and clone method

Tags: java

I am having a little trouble implementing the compareto and clone method in my program, where i get an error that says: "Car is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(java.lang.Object) in java.lang.Comparable". Any help is appreciated:)

This is what i have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Car implements Comparable, Cloneable
{

private String model;
private String color;
private int year;
private int vin_number;
private double price;



public Car(){}

public Car(String model, String color, int year, int vin_number, double price)
{
this.model = model;
this.color = color;
this.year = year;
this.vin_number = vin_number;
this.price = price;
}

public Object clone() { // shallow copy 
try
{
return super.clone();
} 
catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
{ 
return null; 
}

}


public String getModel(){return model;} 
public String getColor(){return color;}
public int getYear(){return year;}
public int getVinNumber(){return vin_number;}
public double getPrice(){return price;}


public void setModel(String newModel){model = newModel;} 
public void setColor(String newColor){color = newColor;}
public void setYear(int newYear){year = newYear;}
public void setVinNumber(int newVinNumber){vin_number = newVinNumber;}
public void setPrice(double newPrice){price = newPrice;}

public String toString()
{
return "Model: " + model + " Color: " + color + " Year: " + year + " Vin Number: " + vin_number + " Price: " + price;
}


public int compareTo(Car o)
    {

if(this.getModel().compareTo(car.getModel())) //gives 1
return 1;

if(car.getModel().compareTo(this.getModel())) //gives -1 
return -1;

else
{
return 0; 
} 

   }

public static void main(String [] args)
{

}


}
```

Comment: If my answer fixed your problem, *please* mark it as accepted and vote it up so people know it worked. If you still have question, comment and ask (this is supposed to be a learning experience). Please don't ignore answers (I saw that you didn't give any attention to an answer to one of your previous questions). Welcome to StackOverflow, btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the type being compared when you implement comparable:

```
class Car implements Comparable<Car>, Cloneable
```

Raw types will use `Object`. You're using a raw type, so right now, `compareTo` must declare `Object` as the parameter, not `Car`.

To fix this error, change `implements Comparable` to `implements Comparable<Car>`